# How to put a UILabel ontop of a UIToolbar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel, uitoolbar

I have a UILabel that shows a character count as the user types into a textfield. Currently it is sitting behind a translucent UIToolbar. I would like the UILabel to be ontop of the UIToolbar. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add it to the `UIToolbar`'s items as a `UIBarButtomItem`. Instantiate it with `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myLabel]`.